# When reading an image from my Player.java class, I get a strange syntax error

Tags: java, syntax

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.*;

    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

    public class Player {
        int x,y;
        Game game;



        try {
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("Cam.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        public Player(Game game){
            this.game = game;
        }

        public void tick(Game game){
            this.game = game;

            x = (game.getWidth() / 2) - 16;
            y = (game.getHeight() / 2) - 16;
        }

        public void render(Graphics g){
            g.drawImage(img, x, y, 50, 50, null);
        }
```

After the line "Game game;" I get a "Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token" error.

Also after the try catch I get a "Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block"

I'm sure all my syntax is correct yet I still get these strange errors. Any suggestions will help, thank you. :)

Comment: *why* is there a `try catch` directly in the class? That is not allowed / possible syntax.

Comment: *"I'm sure all my syntax is correct"* It surly is not.  How  come you think that?

Answer (score 0):

After some playing around with methods I found out the odd syntax errors are due to the try catch not being inside of a method.